# Proving a result using Cauchy Mean Value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]\to R $ and f be differentiable in $(a,b) $  then prove that $\frac {f'(c1)}{a+b}=\frac {f'(c2)}{2c2} $ now rearranging $bf'(c2)-c2f'(c1)=c2f'(c1)-af'(c2) $ . Now  I took $f (x),g (x)=x $ so using LMVT thus $\frac {f (c2)-f (a)}{c2-a}=f'(c1), \frac {f (b)-f (c1)}{b-c1}=f'(c2) $ substituting I have $LHS=c2 (\frac {f (c2)-f (a)}{c2-a})-a(\frac {f (b)-f (c1)}{b-c1}),RHS=b (\frac {f (b)-f (c1)}{b-c1})-c2 (\frac {f (c2)-f (a)}{c2-a} $ Now we see equality is attained at $c2=b,c1=a $. But it doesnt satisfy the condition $c1,c2\in (a,b) $ thus the proof is not correct . Thus I need some other way to tackle it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better choice is $g(x)=x^2$ which is also continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ (notice the $2c_2$ term for motivation to choose $x^2$).

By Cauchy's MVT, we have,

$$\exists c_2\in (a,b)~:~\frac{f'(c_2)}{g'(c_2)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}\\ \implies \frac{f'(c_2)}{2c_2}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b^2-a^2}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\cdot\frac 1{a+b}=\frac{f'(c_1)}{a+b}$$

for some $c_1\in (a,b)$ (by LMVT with $f$ on $[a,b]$)